# Parsing XML from a shell script

Tags: regular-expression, perl, xml

I have a datafile like this:

```
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
    <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 1" />
    <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
    <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
        <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name1" />
    </Key>
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
        <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name2" />
    </Key>
</Key>
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
    <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 2" />
    <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
    <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
        <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name3" />
    </Key>
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
        <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name4" />
    </Key>
</Key>
```

I know the login name of the record I want, and I need to match it to a group. Let's say I want to know what group `name3` is (the answer is `group 3`). Currently I can get the name of the group out of the file with:

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" foreach /name="rsv-group-name".*\ data="([^"]*)"/g;'
```

but I have no idea how to match it with a user. How can I do that in a script?

Comment: How is name3's membership of group 3 determined ?  The text 'group 3' does not feature in the datafile.

Answer (score 2):

The group is `group 2`, not `group 3`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -v '//Key[Key/Value[@name="rsv-login-name" and @data="name3"]]/Value[@name="rsv-group-name"]/@data' -nl file.xml
```

Or, with a query value taken from the command line:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t --var data="'name3'" \
    -v '//Key[Key/Value[@name="rsv-login-name" and @data=$data]]/Value[@name="rsv-group-name"]/@data' -nl file.xml
```

Alternatively,

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t --var data="'name3'" \
    -m '//Key/Key/Value[@name="rsv-login-name" and @data=$data]' \
    -v '../../Value[@name="rsv-group-name"]/@data' -nl file.xml
```

The output from either of these will be `group 2`.

The XPath query looks for a `Key/Key/Value` node that has `name="rsv-login-name"` and `data="name3"`, and for the `Key` that this node is a `Key/Value` node of, it returns the `data` attribute for the `Value` node that has `name="rsv-group-name"`.

The XML I've used here is a slightly modified document that adds a `<root>` tag at the start and a `</root>` end tag at the end, just to make it a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Look into usling xslt scripts to transform or parse your XML, xsltproc is the binary you are looking for and w3cschools have a good getting started guide.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution.

```
$ awk -F= '/name="rsv-group-name"/{g=$NF}/data="name4"/{print substr(g,2,length(g)-5)}' inputfile
```